# Python, Too many open files in system when running the scripts on cluster

Tags: python

I need to parse about 2 millions very small files. But when I run it on the server, everytime it said "Too many open files in system" then the server down.

```
def get_MetaInfo(path):
    proc = psutil.Process()
    with open(path, "r") as file_obj:
        info = file_obj.readlines()
        file_obj.close()
    file_obj.close()
    if len(proc.open_files()) > 1:
        return None
    return info
```

I tried both ways,

```
f = open("xxx.txt", "r")
f.close()
```

OR:

```
with open("xxx.txt", "r") as f:
    info = f.readlines()
return info
```

None of them work, and I tried psutils and make sure that the file is closed.

Is there anyway to see how many exactly open files on the server?

Comment: OS? 32-bits, 64-bits? Other things running? Still occurs on single machine v. cluster?

Comment: Do you have an exception traceback?

Comment: Single machine doesn't have any problem, every time when I run on cluster,  the problem show up probably in 5 sec. I tried to del the file object and use gc.collect(), the problem is gone but it also significantly reduce the speed of my program.

Answer (score 0):

You problem may be related on a limit on the number of open files. You can increase it using [ulimit](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html). `ulimit -n number` and use a high number. Use `ulimit -a` to view the current limits.